# Consider the joint pdf for $X$ and $Y$ given by $f(x,y)=3x, 0 \le y \le x \le 1.$ What is the probability $P(0 \le X\le 0.5, 0.25 \le Y)$?

Tags: statistics

this should be a pretty easy one, but I cannot for the life of me get the supposed answer of $\frac{5}{28}$.

What are my limits of integration supposed to be?

I have tried a million different limits of integration, but the one that seems to make the most sense is:

$\int^\frac{1}{2}_\frac{1}{4} \int^x_\frac{1}{4} 3x \space dy \space dx$.

If someone could just explain to me what the limits of integration are supposed to be and why? Haven't been able to find any examples in my textbooks...

Comment: Those are the correct limits of integration.

Comment: is $\frac{5}{28}$ correct? I've done it a million times and don't get that?

Comment: No, it is way off.